# What does it mean that heaven is taken by violence? Matthew 11:12

Tags: matthew, heaven, john-the-baptist

Matthew 11:12
But from the days of John the baptist until now, the kingdom of the heavens is taken by violence, and [the] violent seize on it. (Darby)

Matthew 11:12  And from the days of John the Baptist until now the kingdom of heaven suffereth violence, and the violent take it by force. (KJV)